# Does JavaScript window.resizeto have maximum values?

Tags: javascript

I am resizing a popup window when an anchor is pressed.
It works well on my desktop computer, but it doesn't on my laptop.

It resizes to a value smaller than the specified in `window.resizeto()`.

Does JavaScript `window.resizeto` have maximum values in browser settings? How do I change those values?

Thanks

Comment: may I guess it never resizes above the screen size?

Comment: are you testing in different browsers? ["Since Firefox 7, it's no longer possible for a web site to change the default size of a window in a browser, according to the following rules:

You can't resize a window or tab that wasn’t created by window.open.
You can't resize a window or tab when it’s in a window with more than one tab."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.resizeTo)

Comment: It goes about 10px more than the screen size. But why can it go above the screen size on my Desktop but not on laptop?

Comment: Same browser. One tab only. Popup screen.

Comment: same browser version?

Comment: All the same! FF 24.0.
Can it be because my desktop has 2 screens and the sum of both is the maximum available width?

Comment: This looks likely. The virtual screen space is the rectangle wrapping the physical screen spaces.

Comment: That was it Jan Dvorak. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My desktop has 2 screens and the maximum width available is the sum of both.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend only on the browser, and OS limitation.
For example, according to Mozilla Dev Network Documentation :

> Specification
>
> DOM Level 0. **Not part of any standard**.

So this only depends of the browser implementation of `window` object.

Check the `resizeTo` method Browser Documentation to see the size limitations.

IE and FF do not seem to make a limitation in the window size, 
**it will depend on how the OS GUI will handle the new size.**

However, MDN says this about `resizeTo` rules :

> 1. You can't resize a window or tab that wasn’t created by window.open.
> 2. You can't resize a window or tab when it’s in a window with more than
>      one tab.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.resizeTo

MDN Documentation should be the most standard documentation. (Even if, as they described, this method is not standard)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't really answer my question.